# Creating a new cookie in Android

Tags: java, android, cookies, cookiemanager

I want to create a new Cookie in Android. When I do:

```
Cookie testCookie = new Cookie();
```

I get an error saying, "Cannot instantiate the type Cookie". All I want to do is create a new cookie and stick it into a cookie store (uses org.apache.http.client CookieStore not java.net.CookieStore or what not). I cannot use HttpCookie because I cannot cast it to a Cookie. Any thoughts here?

Edit (Additional Code):

Here's more or less what I want to do:

```
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import java.net.CookieManager;

CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
CookieStore store = (CookieStore) manager.getCookieStore();

Cookie testCookie = new Cookie();

store.addCookie(testCookie);
```

Comment: Let's see the code that causes this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Cookie`, if what you're talking about is `org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie`, is an Interface and thus cannot be directly instantiated.

Looked at the doc here
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/Cookie.html
for any known implementation of it, I guess [`org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.html) would do it!

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Java, and didn't realize the difference between interfaces and classes. I also see the known implementations which will be insanely useful. :-)